# trying to compare a cv2 window to a saved jpeg

Tags: python, opencv

so as the title says, im trying to compare a cv2 generated live window to a jpeg i have already saved to help create a decently advanced macro im working on.

my solution to this was to repeatedly save the live stream to a file on my pc so that i instead only have to compare image to image but its proving to be more difficult than i thought, idk what exactly is wrong either   (i was following only the first part of this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ks4MPfMq8aQ&ab_channel=sentdex tutorial for the creation of the live window)

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
import keyboard
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time

last_time = time.time()
path = r'C:\Users\srajp\OneDrive\Desktop\Pranav (temporary)\gaming.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)
path2 = r'C:\Users\srajp\OneDrive\Desktop\Pranav (temporary)\maging.jpg'
img2 = cv2.imread(path2)
window_name = 'hackerman'



time.sleep(3)
while True:
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1920,1008)))

    last_time = time.time()
    
    cv2.imshow(window_name, cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

    result=cv2.imwrite(path2, screen)
    if result==False:
        print("Error in saving file")
        
img22 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  

difference = cv2.subtract(img22, img)
r, g, b = cv2.split(difference)


if cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0:
    print('wNIuafiuwfaygewfia')
```

thank you for answering in advance, and i apoligise for any confusing or errored formating as this is my first post, i will read the replies if there are any tomorrow as it is late at night in my timezone as of writing this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCT0o.jpg
this is the image that saves live

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyNix.jpg
thats the default image,
the default image is just my desktop for now but the theory is that i can add multiple if statements for different scenarios that occur while using the macro

Comment: the difference is order of color channels. one is BGR, the other is RGB, and interpreting one as the other exchanges red and blue colors. you already use `cvtColor`, but only for the preview. you can easily fix this if you think a little and maybe if you use a debugger to understand what your code does.

Comment: yeah i noticed that but i thought that having a second image just be the same live saving one but in RGB instead of BGR as seen here
```
img22 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  
```

but i guess i couldve just saved the image in RGB format, dont know why i didnt just think of that

Comment: ok so now im completely stumped, i figured out a way to compare the two when its static  and not being livestreamed, but the moment i live stream it the comparison stops working, i have no idea why this happens and even added a second delay from saving to the image comparison part in hopes that it just takes a while to save but nope


tldr: it works when static but not when live streamed


will send code in a second comment because of word limit

Comment: time.sleep(0.3)

    difference = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)
    b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

    time.sleep(0.3)
    
    if img1.shape == img2.shape:
        print('The images have the same size and channels')

        if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) ==  0:
            print('same image')



nothing changed from the previous code except saving the image as rgb instead of bgr

Comment: perhaps delete this question and start fresh. multiple lines of code, just dumped in a comment,... don't do that. please also review [mre]. irrelevant stuff is a distraction, but it has to be reproducible, i.e. complete.

Comment: oh ok ill do that, sorry for the bad formatting im kinda new to this